# on multiple infinitives

Tags: grammar, writing-style

1. It is my greatest intellectual satisfaction to be able **to** read a line from Plato's dialogues **and see** what is sounds like in any of the languages in which I can read.
2. It is my greatest intellectual satisfaction to be able *to* read a line from Plato's dialogues and *to* see what is sounds like in any of the languages in which I can read.

Which one sounds grammatically and stylistically better?

Answer (score 2):

The first one I would think is more common in English -  this works because it's clear from the sentence that *to* applies both to *read* and *see*.

You would use the second one if this wasn't clear or if you wanted to be more precise or were being more formal.

It's probably worth noting that, unlike in Romance languages, where the infinitive is a single form, in English it is *to /verb/* - 2 words at least, so you have the freedom to split or reuse the *to* - although this has been controversial - mainly due to the influence traditionally of Latin grammar on English.

Comment: The infinitive is only one word, the plain form of the verb. _To_ is a particle and not part of the verb. You can see this when the infinitive follows a modal verb.

Comment: The form without to is called the bare infinitive, and the form with to is called the full infinitive or to-infinitive.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but _to_ is still not part of the verb.

Comment: Grammar books often use imprecise terminology. Barrie is correct; the _to_ is a complementizer for infinitive complements, and is deletable only with certain predicates, and in certain special cases like _to be_-Deletion. In much the same way, _for_ is the complementizer for the **subject** of an infinitive, but is much more often deleted, because subjects of infinitives are often deleted, or moved. _He would like **for** me **to** pick up the check._